# Uppercase and lowercase string

Tags: python, string, discord, discord.py

Is there a way to convert a string to a sequence of uppercase and lowercase letters inside a command? For example, al_sp "Kilometers" → KiLoMeTeRs

Here is what I tried so far but I am not getting any output, any help is appreciated

```
@commands.command()
    async def rand(self, c, upperlower):
        upperlower = upperlower.join([char.upper() if i%2==0 else char.lower() for i, char in enumerate(upperlower)])
        await c.message.delete()
        await c.send(upperlower)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  Do you have an `on_message` event? (if so, please post it).  Finally `upperlower.join` should be `''.join`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Patrick Haugh for pointing this out

I needed to replace `upperlower.join` with `''.join`